# Matplotlib - Add value label on bar chart from column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, label

I have the following df (test2):

```
    Department                    Assignment Status     Overdue      Percentage
2   Business Services             Overdue               393          2.05
5   Operations                    Overdue               4651         3.67
8   Quality Assurance             Overdue               650          2.16
11  Quality Control               Overdue               1046         2.43
14  R&D Operations                Overdue               1645         2.53
```

I want to create a bar chart with 'Department' on the X axis, 'Overdue' on the Y axis and the 'Percentage' as a label on each column.

I have written the code below which has produced the following chart:

```
x=test2['Department']
y=test2['Overdue']
z=test2['Percentage']

my_colors = 'rgbkymc'

figx = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.bar(x, y, color=my_colors)
figx.suptitle('Overdue Training Assignments by Department', fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('Department', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Overdue Count', fontsize=14)

for index, value in enumerate(z):
    plt.text(value, index, str(value));
```

[image]

As you can see, the percentage values do not align with each bar.  Please can someone let me know where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28931224/adding-value-labels-on-a-matplotlib-bar-chart) help?

Comment: Hi Assile, thanks for the response.  I looked at this post earlier and tried for about 30 mins to fit my example but couldn't make it work.  I get the message "BarContainer' object has no attribute 'text'".

Comment: Ah that is because in the example they use a different way of generating the plot. From the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html) it seems to me that you've reversed x and y, perhaps that will help somewhat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah I think I see it now. The proper usage is:

```
plt.text(x, y, s)
```

Where your `x` is index, `y` is the corrosponding 'Overdue' value (plus an offset to make sure it displays above the bar) and then your `s` is already in order.

So that would result something like:

```
for index, value in enumerate(z):
    plt.text(index, y[index] + offset, str(value))
```

Comment: Thanks its worked! Altered it to: for index, value in enumerate(z):
    plt.text(index, 20, str(value));